# PHP Form Server Validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, contacts

So I have created a contact page for our company in HTML and then a separate mail.php script that executes on submit. I have also added a hidden field within the contact page html to reduce spam. I also have on-page jQuery validation which works fine. But I am new to PHP and currently struggling with where precisely I should add my server side validation within my PHP script and the exact format it should take. When researching there seems to be many different ways to format the code so its a bit confusing.

Please help with the changes or additions to code that I need to add in the context of my existing code. All Form Fields Are Required. The HTML code is:

```
<form action="/submit.php" method="post">

<div>First Name:* <input type="text" name="firstname" required></div>

<div>Surname:* <input type="text" name="lastname" required></div>

<div>Email Address:* <input type="text" name="email" required></div>

<div>Telephone Number:* <input type="text" name="telephone" required></div>

<div class="antispam">Leave this empty: <input type="text" name="url">/div>

<div><textarea name="message" required></textarea></div>

<div><select name="enquiry" size="1" required>
 <option value=""> Make a choice:
  <option value="sales">Sales</option>
 <option value="billing">Billing</option>
 <option value="technical">Technical</option>
 <option value="accounts">Accounts</option>
 <option value="business">Business</option>
</select></div>

<div><input type="submit" value="Send" /></div>
</form>
```

The PHP looks like this

```
 <?php 
// if the url field is empty 
if(isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] == ''){

 $youremail = 'me@example.com';

 $body = "This is the result of your contact form:     
First Name: $_POST[firstname]
Last Name: $_POST[lastname]
E-Mail: $_POST[email]
Telephone: $_POST[telephone]
Message: $_POST[message] 
Fav Fruit: $_POST[enquiry]"; 

 if( $_POST['email'] && !preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $_POST['email']) ) {
     $headers = "From: $_POST[email]";     
 } else {
     $headers = "From: $youremail"; 
 }

 mail($youremail, 'Contact Form', $body, $headers ); } 

header('Location: http://www.example.com/message-sent/');
exit;
?>
```

The issue I have at present is if someone disables the jQuery then there needs to be some server side validation for each of the required fields. The only server side validation at present is the hidden field which should be left blank.

I assume that I need to place the required coding just before my email in the PHP code near the top. How would I format this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Since all the fields are required keep an if condition before you start processing anything checking for presence of all the values in $_POST variable

```
if(isset($_POST["firstname"]) && isset($_POST["lastname"]) && ...) {
     // Process after validation
}
```

You are just checking for url which is wrong. Hope this helps.

EDIT: You are not actually making it spam free by hiding the input. It can easily be visible. What actually you can do is add CSRF(Read more about it). Basically this is a hidden field whose value is generated by a random string which cannot be known to anyone(obviously). You only process on server side if this random string matches.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is not quite true. My current php code (above) checks if the url field is filled out and if it is, 'doesn't' send the form. This is the required default behavior of the form. I'm then looking to add the opposite behaviour for all the other fields of the form, so if these other fields are not filled out the form also will not send..

Comment: Why are you checking only for url? what about the others. I can directly go to you submit.php page using curl keeping $_POST['url'] = '' and $_POST['email'] = "some actual email" and it will send mail since you are not checking for any other field

Comment: That's exactly why I'm posting the question and asking for someone to answer. 

I think you're misreading my current PHP code. My code currently checks to ensure the url field is EMPTY and if so sends the form.

This is intended behavior but I now want to ensure the other fields are all completed and cannot be left EMPTY. Any suggestions of what I need to add to my php code (whilst keeping the existing code intact please.)

Comment: What I am saying is checking url field is empty is not the only condition which leads to sending email. What if I send email field="abc@example.com" and keep the url field empty = '' without entering the other fields your form will just submit fine (If js is disabled or if I directly POST to submit.php). But as per your requirement the email should be sent only if all the fields are set.

Comment: Yes we are agreeing with each other @raj454raj - that's correct. Currently you can leave all the "required field" empty or just fill in the ones you want and the form will still send. SO..I am looking for a solution to make the fields required. Can anyone suggest please?

Comment: From a normal html developer point of view you have done that job already. Also you have added jquery validation on top of that - great. But you are unaware of thing called crawling(by curl). If you are expecting genuine users in real world who will go through the normal workflow - go to your form page, fill details and submit the form - You are wrong here. What somebody can do is don't open the page which has the form but open the page to where the form is submitted. By doing this he already bypassed your two levels of validation.

Comment: curl is a unix utility used something like this - curl --data "firstname=raj&lastname=something&email=abc@example.com&url=\'\'"  "url to which make the post request". And done. Since you are checking only url field it is = '' and so it gives permission to send the email. So to avoid this check for all the fields are set or not as provided in my answer. Also read about CSRF and include it in your form. This will generate a random value of that field which the curler cant even guess in any possible condition.This is the maximum explanation I can give. I would say my answer is correct.